# C# SQL Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I'm getting this error (Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.) when trying to run a stored procedure from C# on a SQL Server 2005 database.  I'm not actively/purposefully using transactions or anything, which is what makes this error weird.  I can run the stored procedure from management studio and it works fine.  Other stored procedures also work from C#, it just seems to be this one with issues.  The error returns instantly, so it can't be a timeout issue.  The code is along the lines of:

```
  SqlCommand cmd = null;
  try
  {
      // Make sure we are connected to the database
      if (_DBManager.CheckConnection())
      {
        cmd = new SqlCommand();

        lock (_DBManager.SqlConnection)
        {
          cmd.CommandText = "storedproc";
          cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.Connection = _DBManager.SqlConnection;

          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value);

          int affRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          ...
        }
      }
      else
      {
        ...
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ...
  }
```

It's really got me stumped.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like there is a `TransactionScope` somewhere that is unhappy. The `_DBManager.CheckConnection` and `_DBManager.SqlConnection` sounds like you are keeping a `SqlConnection` hanging around, which I expect will contribute to this.

To be honest, in *most* common cases you are better off just using the inbuilt connection pooling, and `using` your connections locally - i.e.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(...)) { // or a factory method
    // use it here only
}
```

Here you get a clean `SqlConnection`, which will be mapped to an unmanaged connection via the pool, i.e. it doesn't create an *actual* connection each time (but will do a logical reset to clean it up).

This also allows much more flexible use from multiple threads. Using a `static` connection in a web app, for example, would be horrendous for blocking.

Comment: The only reason I keep a single connection is because I do a fairly large amount of inserts and didn't want to have the slowdown of opening connections each time.  I will try this method and see how quick it is.  Still doesn't explain why this once working code now doesn't work, even though nothing has changed.

Comment: Oh also, in Activity Monitor in Management Studio I can see 1 under "Open Transactions" for my connection.  Which means there is a transaction hanging around.  Is there any way to get more details on the open transaction?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Opened connection(s) will commonly remain in the pool for the app life; killing it fully isn't easy short of disabling pooling, sacrificing the performance benefits of the pool.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems that you are utilizing an already opened connection. May be there's a transaction pending previously on the same connection.

Comment: You appear to be onto something here.  If I .Close() and .Open() the connection at the beginning of the call the stored proc works.  This hasn't been needed in the past though, and other programs with the same code (but different stored proc) are still working.  I can't find any different code between the programs except the stored proc name & params.  I also already call reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); command.Dispose(); (where appropriate) after each query.  Is there any way to ensure transactions are closed?

Comment: You might wanna check out the store procedure. Are you utilizing any transaction from there... Or is there any triggers on table which will by default to a transaction.

Comment: In a layered architecture it's always better to implements automicity of actions at Business logic layer however most layer designer make their dal methods atomic opening and closing connections on each dal operation. If you want to hang around with one connection problem then open a connection on logic layer and then pass it on to dal.. this way you'll have a track of the connection being used. By the way using a single connection and then  allowing synchronous access to it will decrease the performance of your application will be quite drastic I belive.

Comment: Are you sure you are closing connection with in the lock... What if you acquire a lock and another request is waiting for the same lock to finish... The connection can be reclaimed as soon as the lock block is done... so if the connection is not closed then you might have a problem...

Comment: Nothing wrong inside the actual stored proc.  No triggers, no transactions.  The code has been working fine for a couple of months now, no idea what made it stop working.  Connection has been kept open for the duration of the program to allow quicker query speeds.  I will swap to trying to utilize the connection pool and see how it goes.  I don't really like the idea of handling connection open/closing in the logic, I'd rather it be handled by the DAL which is the way it currently works.  Thanks for the suggestions.